# Using Mathematica to calculate expected time to absorption

Tags: probability-or-statistics, markov-chains

I am trying to solve a standard ETA on a birth-death process with $n$ states $\in \{0,\cdots,n-1\}$ where state $n-1$ is absorbing. Also $\mu_i$ is the expected time to absorption starting at state $i$. Hence $\mu_{n-1}=0$ and everywhere else:
$$\mu_i=1+ \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij}\mu_j$$

Also, constraints are $i,j \in \{0,\cdots,n-1\}$ and:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
p_{ij}=\frac{n-i}{n}(1-q) \text{ for } j=i+1\\
p_{ij}=q \text{ for } j=i-1\\
p_{ij}=1-q-\frac{n-i}{n}(1-q)\text { for } i=j\\
0        \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

I'm interested to solve this (for arbitrary n), and **find $\mu_0$**. using *Mathematica*, in order to learn to use *Mathematica* in more complicated cases. Because I'm completely new to using it (though I can code), I would appreciate your help.

Here is what I attempted:

```
 RSolve[{a[n] == 1 + q* a[-1 + n] + ((-n + m)*(1 - q)* a[1 + n])/ m +(1 - q - (1 - q)*(-n + m) /m)*a[n], a[m] == 0}, a[n],n]
```

Where i in the math is replaced by n in the code, and n is replaced by m.

I would appreciate some explanation on any code you write.

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you provide the equations in *Mathematica* code?

Comment: The problem is I cannot even formulate the recurrence properly. I have been trying to do this using Rsolve, but I'm unable to enforce the conditions given above.

Comment: f[i_, j_, n_, alpha_] = 
 Piecewise[{{(n - i)/n, j == i + 1}, {alpha, i == j + 1}}]

Comment: The expression for j==i+1 in the ASCII version differs from the picture version. Is $p_{i,j}$ a transmission matrix? Rows don't add up to 1.

Comment: Sorry about that, missed the normalizing factor in the description

Comment: There are still differences. q in the picture, alpha in the code.

Comment: With your latest change the m's become imaginary for n=3,4,5. That can't be your intention. Could you think it over again?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't clear enough (assumed the birth-death declaration would be clear). Ignore my code, but my math should be correct now. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'm still getting complex times ...

Comment: Still not correct. m's imaginary for n==3. BTW you let i,j start above at 0, but you'll probably want to have them start at 1.

Comment: Your new introduction of $\mu_0$ conflicts with the number of states that you mentioned (n).

Comment: I suggest you delete your question until you've made up your mind as to the precise equations and undelete it then. You've gone to 10 changes in rapid succession, not counting the many more that occurred within the grace period of 5 minutes.

Comment: As to solving for general n: not likely (search this site for 'abstract vector' for more discussions on this).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: Although I upvoted both attempts at an answer, it looks like it is futile to address this question as it seems to be a moving target.

Comment: @jens You're right, 
 I've more or less given up. The question hasn't been stable for much more than a minute in the last hour.

Comment: I apologize if it appears to be the case. I have added clarifications. Frankly the off-by-one problems are not what I cared about. I want to understand how these problems can be addressed with mathematica in general. I tried to construct a problem that is similar to those I will need to solve. I cannot delete the question per suggestion, because it already has answers. The current version is final.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
P[n_] := SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> (n - i - 1)/ n, 
                      {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> q}, {n, n}]
mu[n_] := Array[m, n]
Solve[mu[3] == 1 + P[3].mu[3], mu[3]]
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the last line is doing?

Comment: @GammaAmino It's solving a 3x3 system. I hope you're kidding.

Comment: Not kidding, yes, clearly it's solving a 3x3 system, but I'm not sure if it is the system I'm looking for. I.e. I'm trying to understand how P[3].mu[3] is mapping to the equations I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Belisarius was almost there but he forgot a constraint (m[n]==0). The following should work:

```
P[n_] := SparseArray[
           {
            {i_, j_} /;j == i + 1 -> (n - i - 1)/n (1 - α), 
            {i_, j_} /;j == i - 1 -> q
           }, {n, n}
         ]
mu[n_] := Array[m, n]
Block[{n = 3},
 Solve[{mu[n] == 1 + P[n].mu[n], m[n] == 0}, Append[mu[n], α]]
]

(* {{m[1] -> (-1 - q)/q^2, m[2] -> -(1/q), m[3] -> 0, α -> (-3 - 2 q - 3 q^2)/q}} *)
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not explaining this right, but it is possible to get a solution for n in general rather than passing in a fixed n?

Comment: Maybe forget about my code, my math is the right reference above. How could I calculate the formula for general n.